# Explicit generic interface with class inheritance

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, interface, explicit

**GENERIC INTERFACE**:

```
interface ICloneable < T >  
{  
    T CopyFrom (T source);  
    T CopyFrom (T source);  
    T CopyTo (T destination);  
}
```

**CLASS**: Implements generic interface:

```
public class Entity: ICloneable < Entity >  
{  
    public int ID { get; set; }  
    public Entity CopyFrom (Entity source)  
    {  
    this.ID = source.ID;  
    return (this);  
    }  
}
```

**WINDOWS FORM**: This form should only accept T types that implement the above generic interface.

```
public sealed partial class Computer < T >: System.Windows.Forms.Form  
{  
    private T ObjectCurrent { get; set; }  
    private T ObjectOriginal { get; set; }  
    public Computer (HouseOfSynergy.Library.Interfaces.ICloneable < T > @object)
    {  
        this.ObjectOriginal = (T) @object;  
        this.ObjectCurrent = @object.Clone();  
    }  
    private void buttonOk_Click (object sender, System.EventArgs e)  
    {  
        ((ICloneable < T >) this.ObjectOriginal).CopyFrom(this.ObjectCurrent);  
        this.Close();  
    }  
}
```

As you would guess, the call to `((ICloneable < T >) this.ObjectOriginal).CopyFrom(this.ObjectCurrent);` is perfectly legal. However, the code above does not *ensure* that the type T passed in to the class implements `ICloneable < T >`. I have forced it through the constructor but that looks to be in bad taste.

The following two constructs are illegal and I wonder why:

```
class Computer < ICloneable < T >>: System.Windows.Forms.Form
```

OR

```
class Computer < T where T: ICloneable < T > >: System.Windows.Forms.Form
```

Any thoughts on how to achieve this?

Comment: Are you talking about Java or C# ?

Comment: why the java tag? This is C# code, obviously.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. Fixed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of the first construct you could use

```
class Computer<T> : System.Windows.Forms.Form where T : ICloneable<T>
```

Instead of the second one you could use

```
class Computer <T, TCloneable>: System.Windows.Forms.Form 
    where TCloneable : ICloneable<T>
```

Comment: Thanks! I could not find an example of this. Wasn't sure what combination of keywords to search with. If you know of any articles explaining various constructs like this, please let me know. All I found was generic interface inheritance but nothing combined with class inheritance.

Comment: The second construct is the one I used. Regarding the first one, wouldn't that mean sending two distinct objects to the Computer class? If yes, then that would in bad design in my particular context because the T object is the one that needs to implement ICloneable. Am I correct in assuming this?

Comment: The constraint in the first case means that the class `T` should also implement `ICloneable<T>`. So it could be a single object. For example it could be an instance of your `Entity` class -  `public class Entity: ICloneable < Entity >` - in this case any instance of this class is an `Entity`, but also an `ICloneable<Entity>`. Whether this design is good or bad can only be judged depending on the context.

Comment: My bad. I meant to say the first construct is the one I used. The second one seems to allow two parameters which leaves more room for error and would be redundant in my context. Thanks.