# Generic Windows Form Template

Tags: c#, winforms, generics, reflection

I am creating a generic Windows Form that accepts T and uses reflection with custom attributes to create labels and input controls at run-time.

Example:

```
class GenericForm<T>: Form where T : ICloneable<T>  
{  
}
```

Here's a link to a previous question for the form code: [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8771685/explicit-generic-interface-with-class-inheritance).

This form could accept the following entity class as an example:

```
class Vehicle: ICloneable<Vehicle>  
{  
    public int Id { get; set; }  
    public int Name { get; set; }  
    public int Description { get; set; }  
}
```

As you could imagine, the magic behind the form would use reflection to determine data types, validation criteria, preferred control types to use, etc.

Rather than re-inventing the wheel, I thought it would be worth asking on SO if anyone knows of such frameworks. Needless to say, I'm looking for something simple rather than a bulky framework.

Comment: We use [Lightswitch](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/lightswitch) at work for this type of thing (sort of).

Comment: I have only read about LightSwitch and have not tried it. From what I know, it is independent from Visual Studio and better suited to a sub-set of applications.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'it is independent from Visual Studio'. Yes it is a separate Microsoft product that you would have to license. No it is not a separate application, it is more like a Visual Studio addin. Without knowing what type of application you're aiming to create with this, it would be hard to know whether Lightswitch would be a good fit. Seeing that you're after Winforms generation probably not though since Lightswitch generates Silverlight applications.

Comment: Hmmm... It's been about 15 hours since my post and I've finally come up with my own darn framework of custom attributes and a windows form that accepts any class while supporting most clr types. It allows you to pass an instance of < T > and provides full editing capabilities including validation, help and apply/cancel functionality.

Comment: @M.Babcock, yes I'm stuck with winforms applications. The above scenario I'm trying to code for will save me from having to custom develop about 800 entity forms!

Comment: I once created a Visual Studio Add-In that creates forms depending on a Sql Server Connection DURING DESIGN TIME. That's cooler than runtime creation. There was no reflection but I was able to edit some forms if I wanted to :)

Comment: Hmm why not share this valuable piece of code with lazy coders like myself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, there are no frameworks that generate the UI code at runtime. There are plenty of tools (code-generators) that do this before. But you wouldn't have the advantage of "only" changing the code - you'd had an extra step where you would need to start the code generator.

If you really want to create the UI information at runtime - I'd generate Attributes for your properties, that would tell your UI generator how to deal with this property (if no Attribute is given - have a default for your datatypes). It's a lot of coding but could save you time for small to medium projects in the future.

Another thing you could do is to externalize your UI information into an XML file and have a generator for that one. There's actually a framework that does that - have a look at the [re-motion](https://www.re-motion.org/web/) framework. I don't know if the part of the UI is free but it has some functionality (i.e. mixins) that could help you fulfilling your task.

Comment: Re-Motion seems to have what I need but is tied to the LPGL which I cannot use for commercial products with too much flexibility.

Comment: And yes, using attributes is the way I'm currently generating UI on-the-fly.

Comment: Okay - then I'd go for attributes too. I looked into that field myself but there is nothing that generates UI on the fly - but there are a lot of not so good working code generators.

Answer (score 1):

[eXpressApp Framework (XAF)](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Application_Framework/) can generate UI on the fly. In a simple case, a programmer will create business entities only, and will not care of UI at all.

Comment: eXpressApp Framework seems to contain all I need. Just have to budget for an annual subscription now :).