# Make windows form generic

Tags: c#, winforms

One year after a similare question has been posted on SO.
[Generic Windows Form Template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8778535/generic-windows-form-template)

Do you know if there're a better way to make a windows form generic, here's what I'd like to do:

```
public partial class EntryPointEditForm<T>  : Form where T : ICriteriaObject<T>
{}
```

But an error is thrown telling me that: 
no suitable method found to override
on the method:

```
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
```

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth: I believe you are correct, but your reason is wrong.  The designer does not need to do anything with the generic parameter; the designer only works with the base class.

Comment: @Slaks My understanding (although my memory is hazy on it, it was a while ago) was that the design tries to instantiate the class being designed, but cannot because it has no `T`, hence resolving `T` to a strong type by using an interim seems to work.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth: No.  The designer instantiates the _base_ class, then explicitly reads the contents of the `InitializeComponent` method.  This is why you can design an abstract form class.

Comment: @Slaks I get you, and I've just re-read my post about it and came to the same conclusion. I even said as much in my post lol, just shows how useless my memory is on this particular topic - must be the reason I wrote it all down.

Comment: Managed to delete the comment with my post link in it. [Further reading](http://adamhouldsworth.blogspot.co.uk/2010/02/winforms-visual-inheritance-limitations.html).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to change the partial class declaration in the `.Designer.cs` file to also be generic.

However, I don't think that the VS designer supports generic form classes.
You may need to make a non-generic abstract form to use with the designer, then make a generic class that inherits from it for you to actually use.

Comment: Thanks, it works. I will vote your question as accepted in 11min.

Comment: @JohnSmith: Did the designer work with the generic class, or did you need to apply my workaround?

Comment: Give me 2sec, I try to load the designer.

Comment: @Slaks In this instance, unless `EntryPointEditForm<T>` is used as a base class there should be no problem.

Comment: The designer is loading fine using generic class.